# Category Flat Data problem: description is missing in flat table without indexing error

Tags: magento-1.7, category, flat-catalog, flat-indexer

I'm working on M1 CE 1.7.0.2.

I've enabled Use Flat Catalog Category from backend **(catalog/frontend/flat_catalog_category = 1)**.

Then I **reindex** `php shell/indexer.php --reindexall` without any error.
When I check indexes in backend: all lines are green.

When I check my categories on frontend: description and category image are not showing.

**If I disable the Flat Catalog Category all goes fine back again.**

Generally an exception is thrown during `reindex` of `catalog_category_flat` but here, nothing.

Is anyone had facing this issue?
How can I debugging indexer to ensure he catch all category parameters before saving into **catalog_category_flat_store_x** db table?

Thank you in advance for your help!

---

After a deep analysis, I've found the code responsible of this situation.

The method in cause is responsible of retrieving attributes values when index process is saving data to flat table:

**Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Flat::_getAttributeTypeValues().**

```
protected function _getAttributeTypeValues($type, $entityIds, $sid)
{
    $select = $this->_getWriteAdapter()->select()
        ->from(
            array('def' => $this->getTable(array('catalog/category', $type))),
            array('entity_id', 'attribute_id')
        )
        ->joinLeft(
            array('store' => $this->getTable(array('catalog/category', $type))),
            'store.entity_id = def.entity_id AND store.attribute_id = def.attribute_id AND store.store_id = '.$sid,
            array('value' => $this->_getWriteAdapter()->getCheckSql('store.value_id > 0',
                $this->_getWriteAdapter()->quoteIdentifier('store.value'),
                $this->_getWriteAdapter()->quoteIdentifier('def.value'))
            )
        )
        ->where('def.entity_id IN (?)', $entityIds)
        ->where('def.store_id = ?', Mage_Catalog_Model_Abstract::DEFAULT_STORE_ID);
    return $this->_getWriteAdapter()->fetchAll($select);
}
```

The problem is at line 829:

> where('def.store_id = ?',
>   Mage_Catalog_Model_Abstract::DEFAULT_STORE_ID);

This is a `$select` output example analyzed during my debug:

> SELECT `def`.`entity_id`, `def`.`attribute_id`, IF(store.value_id > 0,
>   `store`.`value`, `def`.`value`) AS `value` FROM
>   `catalog_category_entity_text` AS `def` LEFT JOIN
>   `catalog_category_entity_text` AS `store` ON store.entity_id =
>   def.entity_id AND store.attribute_id = def.attribute_id AND
>   store.store_id = 43 WHERE (def.entity_id IN ('1', '164')) AND
>   (def.store_id = 0)

Look at the end: **def.store_id = 0**

This condition exclude the description that are saved at store view level.
It means category description is indexed only if description is save on default scope.

My categories get no description value at default scope, then receive a value only at store view level.

**If I comment the line 829 then reindex, it works like a charm.**

Then I thought maybe it was updated in a newer release of Magento CE. 
I've checked the 1.9.1 and this method hasn't changed.

Is this situation normal? 
I think it's not.

I hope a Magento Guru will get through here to give his advice.

Cheers.

Comment: Have you checked if description values are in the database table catalog_category_flat_store_x ?

Comment: Is it a custom template? Can you add the code you use to display image/description?

Comment: Justly I've checked from db and description is empty ("select a.description from catalog_category_flat_store_x"). And if i check catalog_category_entity_text (with description attribute_id), the row related to the store exists (obvious because i see the description into backend when editing the category).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Then I thought maybe it was updated in a newer release of Magento CE. I've checked the 1.9.1 and this method hasn't changed.

That's (un)fortunately not right. In Magento 1.8.0.0 the mehtod changed to:

```
/**
 * Return attribute values for given entities and store of specific attribute type
 *
 * @param string $type
 * @param array $entityIds
 * @param integer $storeId
 * @return array
 */
protected function _getAttributeTypeValues($type, $entityIds, $storeId)
{
    $select = $this->_getWriteAdapter()->select()
        ->from(
            array('def' => $this->getTable(array('catalog/category', $type))),
            array('entity_id', 'attribute_id')
        )
        ->joinLeft(
            array('store' => $this->getTable(array('catalog/category', $type))),
            'store.entity_id = def.entity_id AND store.attribute_id = def.attribute_id '
                . 'AND store.store_id = ' . $storeId,
            array('value' => $this->_getWriteAdapter()->getCheckSql(
                'store.value_id > 0',
                $this->_getWriteAdapter()->quoteIdentifier('store.value'),
                $this->_getWriteAdapter()->quoteIdentifier('def.value')
            ))
        )
        ->where('def.entity_id IN (?)', $entityIds)
        ->where('def.store_id IN (?)', array(Mage_Catalog_Model_Abstract::DEFAULT_STORE_ID, $storeId));
    return $this->_getWriteAdapter()->fetchAll($select);
}
```

See: https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.8/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Category/Flat.php#L839-L867

Comment: I've checked this method too fast. You're absolutely right. It's working fine now! Thank you sv3n.